# How to add markdown's image folder in a sqlite database?

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, markdown

I'm writing an Android application that consists in a collection of university notes taken in markdown.
I would like to save these notes into an sqlite database, in such a way that, when I will write new notes or modify old ones, I'd need simply to upload the new files in the database and update the db version in the app.

I'm able to add a table in my database whose tuples contain the plain markdown I wrote.
Though, I would like to be able to load in the database the "image" folder in which I have put the images I refer to in the markdown files.
***----------------------------------------------------- EDIT 1 ---------------------------------------------------------------***
In case I've not been clear, let me give you some context:

I have a folder in my PC in which I've put many markdown files.
In the same folder I've created a folder called "**imgs**", and whenever I want to add an image in any of the markdown files I write something like this within the markdown file:
*<img src="imgs/image_name.jpg">*.
Let me show you what it looks like:
[the folder where I've put all my markdown files and the image folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsaDA.png)
So, suppose I've just downloaded the picture of a cat and called such picture cat.jpg.
Suppose I want to add this picture in the markdown file called ***1_introduction.md***.
I would simply put the image in the folder ***imgs*** and write in 1_introduction.md the following:*<img src="imgs/cat.jpg">*

What I've explained above is simply what I've always done on my PC for the last couple of years: I wrote plain markdown files and saved images into a folder (as probably 99% of people do when dealing with markdown files!)

NOW I want to store these markdown files (and obviously the ***imgs*** folder as well) into the database of an Android application.
MOREOVER I want to be able to modify the content of these markdown files (locally, in my PC. I don't want users to be able to modify these files) and give the possibility to the users of the Android app to retrieve the updated content simply by updating the app (NOT reinstalling it).

my final questions are:

- is there any approach suggested by the Android community to handle this scenario? In case, what is it?
- In case there is not, is it possible to save the ***imgs*** folder in the database, along with the markdown files? and, if it's possible, how should I modify the html tags *<img src="imgs/image_name.jpg">* in order for it to work?
- The other alternative would be to save the folder that contains both the markdown files and the imgs folder in the folder ***assets***, but wouldn't the user need to redownload the app in order to witness the changes I'd make?
  Thank you in advance!

Comment: `in the same folder where I've put notes.md ` In a folder? You said you had put them in the database. Please edit your post.

Comment: Who is displaying those .md files? And where does that .md file reside when it is displayed?

Comment: You would need to add each image as a separate record in the database, and the code that displays the Markdown would need to query for each image is encounters in the Markdown markup.

Comment: Hi blackapps, sorry if it was not clear.i hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Hi eskwayrd, thank you for your answer. that sounds very time consuming though. Do you know if there is a way to load these images into a folder in my Android app, in such a way that I could add images to it whenever I want and ask users to update the app in order to retrieve the new images?

Comment: @blackapps , I didn't know I could mention you. I've answered your comment a few days ago :)

Comment: @eskwayrd , I didn't know I could mention you. I've answered your comment a few days ago as well :)

Comment: You did not answer my questions at all.

Comment: `suppose that I create a folder in my PC in which I put a markdown file and called it notes.md.` So you created a folder C:\notes.md and put a file in it with full path C:\notes.md\notes.md ? If not then tell real names and full paths.

Comment: @blackapps   I've edited again the question, hoping it's clearer now.  
In the meanwhile I''l answer your specific questions.
Q: 
`in the same folder where I've put notes.md  In a folder? You said you had put them in the database. Please edit your post.`
A:  
I still don't know where to put the markdown files within the Android app, I'm asking for advices on how to approach the problem.

Comment: @blackapps

Q:
`Who is displaying those .md files? And where does that .md file reside when it is displayed?`
A: It doesn't reside anywhere yet. I was thinking I could put the content of the markdown files within a field of an sqlite table, but I've not implemented it yet.

Comment: @blackapps 
Q:  
`So you created a folder C:\notes.md and put a file in it with full path C:\notes.md\notes.md ? If not then tell real names and full paths`
A: I don't think it's relevant for my question. I've no problems displaying my markdown files on my PC. I want to put them in an Android app and display them WITHIN the app.  Anyways, my markdown files are saved in the folder with path C:/notes, the content of this folder is shown in the image I've attached to my post.

Comment: You still did not tell which app on your Android device should display the .md files.

Comment: @blackapps An app that I'm developing in Java with Android Studio. the compileSdkVersion is 29.

Comment: I would copy the whole notes directory to assets. If you change a file then publish a new version of your app.

Comment: @blackapps but this way the user would need to reinstall the app, right? I want him just to update the app, not reinstall it.

Comment: I don't develop for Android, so I can't help directly. But I think you may be confused: updating an app should (I think) be downloading the new version and installing it over the old version. Re-installing an app would imply removing the app and all of its data first.